# DataTables warning: table id=example - Invalid JSON response. I have no response from server

Tags: server, datatables-1.10

I am trying to make [DataTables.js (Server-side Processing)](https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/simple.html) working for my custom CMS, unfortunately the default server-side script isn't returning any result.

[image]

Of course I entered my database credentials into it, and chosen an existing table in my database.

I have no error in my apache logs.

This guy in DataTables.js forum had exactly same issue:

https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/27049/datatables-warning-table-id-example-invalid-json-response-but-no-response-with-server-side-exampl

But apparently he solved it by installing PDO in the server. I verified and my server has already PDO installed.

Any idea?

**Edit**

As asked, here is the code I am using. Actually it's exactly same as the example there: https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/simple.html

HTML

```
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>First name</th>
            <th>Last name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>First name</th>
            <th>Last name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

JavaScript

```
$('#example').DataTable( {
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": "/server_processing.php"
} );
```

PHP

```
<?php

/*
 * DataTables example server-side processing script.
 *
 * Please note that this script is intentionally extremely simply to show how
 * server-side processing can be implemented, and probably shouldn't be used as
 * the basis for a large complex system. It is suitable for simple use cases as
 * for learning.
 *
 * See http://datatables.net/usage/server-side for full details on the server-
 * side processing requirements of DataTables.
 *
 * @license MIT - http://datatables.net/license_mit
 */

/* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
 * Easy set variables
 */

// DB table to use
$table = 'node';

// Table's primary key
$primaryKey = 'nid';

// Array of database columns which should be read and sent back to DataTables.
// The `db` parameter represents the column name in the database, while the `dt`
// parameter represents the DataTables column identifier. In this case simple
// indexes
$columns = array(
    array( 'db' => 'nid', 'dt' => 0 ),
    array( 'db' => 'type',  'dt' => 1 ),
    array( 'db' => 'language',   'dt' => 2 ),
    array( 'db' => 'title',     'dt' => 3 ),
);

// SQL server connection information
$sql_details = array(
    'user' => '******',
    'pass' => '******',
    'db'   => '******',
    'host' => '******'
);


/* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
 * If you just want to use the basic configuration for DataTables with PHP
 * server-side, there is no need to edit below this line.
 */

require( 'ssp.class.php' );

echo json_encode(
    SSP::simple( $_GET, $sql_details, $table, $primaryKey, $columns )
);
```

Here is a link to the sample script in my server:

http://tests.krown.ch/examples/server_side/simple.html

**Edit 2**

My server has PDO working on it:

[image]

I also checked with `class_exists('PDO')`

The credentials are good because if I change them, I will get some other errors telling me credentials are not good or database was not found.

The table in database I am testing is that one:

[image]

Comment: Show your DataTables initialization code, HTML markup and server response.

Comment: I posted the HTML, JavaScript and PHP code. There is no server response is empty

Comment: Then the problem is in your server-side script. There could be multiple things, check credentials, table name, PHP PDO support, PHP or your web server error logs for clues why your script doesn't produce any output.

Comment: I already double checked everything. Credentials are good, PDO is installed and I have nothing in my logs

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is you don't have the file `ssp.class.php`. You have to have this file as well for the Server Side processing to work. You can get it from GIThub [here](https://github.com/DataTables/DataTablesSrc/blob/master/examples/server_side/scripts/ssp.class.php).

You might have to modify it based on what you are connecting to, but based on what is in your question it will probably work as is.